# How to go on about adding a non editable meta data section for all the users in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress plugin. In this I would like to add a non editable metadata section for all the users.

What I am thinking is: an admin-only editable field in each user's profile. Or a non editable field like username which can only be added once.

Can I do it? Or is there any other better way of achieving this?

Comment: have you tried something>>?? show the code

Comment: I am sorry, didn't you understand the question? I am asking how to go on about it. I don't even know if what I am asking is possible or not! So is it possible? The thing is if this is not possible, what I might be doing will need a write up from the scratch. I don't want to do that. If you could say this is possible, then sure I will write it up and paste it here, Thanks a lot.!

Comment: @defiant .. are you willing to show them in admin section only?

Comment: @GopalRathore It doesn't matter to be frank. The users doesn't need the control of this meta data. But it is way easier if I can add this to the profile field like the username. Usernames can't be changed once created, so once this value is added, there should be now way to edit it by the user. But yeah if thats not possible, I have the option to add this meta data from admin section.

Comment: when the user will be adding this metadata?

Comment: It will be added by admin. The data will be added first when the admin installs the plugin. And then at each user registrations.